# Passing resource id from Activity to initialize custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewgroup

This is a followup of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33197836/1639556) where @pskink adviced me to implement custom ViewGroup that will paint what I need. I succeeded with a prototype using hard coded values. I want to move it to further level where I can pass initialization parameters from an Activity. I need to pass a resource id and open an image to be used in onPaint method.

This is the activity. I can get the ViewGroup instance there but it is already instantiated so it makes no sense to pass the resource id in its constructor. I tried to use a setter but I need a Context to initialize Drawable from the resource.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
    hiddenPicture = (TileGroupLayout) findViewById(R.id.hidddenPictureArea);
    hiddenPicture.setPictureResource(R.drawable.pic_cute_girl);
```

ViewGroup's setter does not have the context like the constructor.

```
public void setPictureResource(int resourceId) {
    int pictureResource = resourceId;
    mCustomImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic_cute_girl);
    pictureRect = mCustomImage.getBounds();
}
```

How to get from this issue? I need to pass the initialization parameter before ViewGroup is painted. Activity has many onXY() methods to override but there is no similar ViewGroup methods. What is its lifecycle?

Comment: k0sh is right: you can use `View#getContext`

Comment: Is my approach right? Pass parameter from Activity's onCreate using ViewGroup's setter and then override onDraw?

Comment: I am android rookie, I do not want to walk all dead end streets :-)

Comment: ok when it comes to `ViewGroup` its better to override `dispatchDraw` or (not 100% sure) `draw` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your `ViewGroup` class, just call `getContext()` from anywhere inside of the class.
**Edit**
on top of getting the context from the `ViewGroup` class you actually don't need to call `getContext().getResources()` instead you should call `getResources()` directly.

Comment: Thanks I moved further. Lets see if it will work. I am especially interested in the lifecycle.